# Set up writing access to external drive

Tags: android, ubuntu

I need get writting access to /dev/sda5. It's place where located android sdk. I can't run adb and sdk manager. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 x64

I tried this

```
mount -o uid=username,gid=groupname /dev/sdc /path/to/mount
```

and this

```
chmod -R 0777 /mnt/external
```

It's not helped.

P.S. Sorry for my English

**UPDATED:**

Sorry I forget say that /dev/sda5 is NTFS

**SOLVED:**

http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue `mount -o rw,remount /dev/sdc` to remount it with read and write rights.